# What is the purpose of the lower lens on some laptops?

Tags: webcam, hp-elitebook, components

I have tried reading the [HP EliteBook 2540p manual](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c02664684-1.pdf) but it does not seem to label it anywhere.

I've noticed that this model in particular isn't the only one, there are quite a few models that have it and I'm not entirely sure what it is, my first thought is that it's a webcam but the webcam is at the top of the screen on this model?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that its an ambient light sensor - which the [specifications confirms it has](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02068850-2%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1408953896181.876444892.199480143). Apparently they arn't terribly good, and there's a quite of information on how to turn them off, but I'm reasonably certain that's what it is.

Comment: Oh yeah that would make sense because if you press fn + F11 then it toggles the ambient light sensor. Yup, page 18 of the manual confirms it, thanks!